# Ramda, pass value in pipe if condition pass

Tags: ramda.js

```
export const getValueFromPsetProperty = (pset: string, property: string) => R.pipe(
  R.prop('pSets'),
  R.find(R.propEq('name', pset)),
  R.propOr([], 'properties'),
  R.find(R.propEq('name', property)),
  R.propOr(null, 'value'),
  R.ifElse(isValueValid, null,R.identity),
);
```

The last pipe does not work. What I want to do is to pass the value if `isValueValid` is true. How should I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're using `R.ifElse` correctly. All first three arguments should be functions:

1. A predicate function
2. The function to execute if the predicate is true
3. The function to execute if the predicate is false

So from what you're describing, you want to return the value unchanged if `isValueValid` returns true. In this case your `R.ifElse` should be:

```
R.ifElse(isValueValid, R.identity, someOtherFunction)
```

You may want to consider `R.unless` which will run a function only if a predicate is false. If value is valid, then the `R.unless` returns it unchanged.

```
R.unless(isValueValid, someFunctionIfValueIsNotValid);
```

Comment: You should also wrap `null` with R.always.